# How to disable uncaught C++ exception reporting by Java on Windows?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I debug application that calls some Java code over JNI and implements some callbacks from Java to C++ also via JNI. The application is huge and very complex, and sometimes uncaught C++ exception appears during debugging inside JNI methods implemented by application.

Java virtual machine catches such exceptions and writes to standard output a lot of useless information about the error that never helps me to identify the problem.

Instead, of course, I prefer that Visual Studio debugger will catch such exceptions as usual (i. e. in application that don't load Java and don't call it via JNI).

How to disable uncaught C++ exception inside JNI method reporting by Java on Windows, so Visual Studio debugger will catch such exceptions instead of Java?

Comment: You could read through the exception handler at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l2317 and maybe find a good place to set a breakpoint using Visual Studio? Also, do you have this behavior as well if you have the debugger attached?

Comment: Yes, I have this behavior during debug with Visual Studio GUI. I use Java downloaded from official Java website, is it the same as openjdk one?

Comment: The core should be the same, yes. Can't you configure visual studio to break on thrown exceptions, like other IDEs?

Comment: Yes, but it will make too much false positives; it is required to catch uncaught exceptions only (i. e. ones that will result in crash), if exception is caught, it is part of normal program execution, and they appear countless times.